# HTML / CSS | 2 divs next to each other - left div 250px and right div 100%

Tags: html

first of all I am trying to programming a website...
Now my question:

I want to have on the left side of my website a div which has a height of 100% and a width of 250px

On the right side of my website I want a div which has a height of 100% and a width of 100% too...

BUT

If I do this then my right div is to big for my Monitor but I want to have it perfectly fit so that i dont need to scroll to the right..

PS: I want that the left div is fixt on 250px width!

Hopefully anyone know what I mean

[The white one is the left div | The black one is the right div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wASOH.png)

Comment: PPS: i want to scale my window and the right div need to change his width automaticaly so that all fit in

Answer (score 2):

You can try `flex`: for more visit [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flex)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}
#parent{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  
  }


#child1{
  width:250px;
  background-color:green;
  }

#child2{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
<div id='child1'>child1</div>
<div id='child2'>child2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks! ^^... but how can i do this that the border is not white... so i want it to fill 100% of the screen not to 98%.

Comment: Sry I don't see a difference... :o

Comment: it need to be looks like this:

Comment: <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<div id="contairofthemall" style="width: 100%;">

  <div id="divone" style="height:100%; width:250px; position: absolute; background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div id="divtwo" style="height:100%; width:100%;  background-color: red;"></div>

</div>
</body>

Comment: @Ryl0x try using viewport `vh`  value.

Comment: <html>
<body>

<style>

html, body {
}
#parent{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;

  }


#child1{
  width:250px;
  background-color:green;
  }

#child2{
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color:red;
  }

</style>

<div id='parent'>
<div id='child1'>child1</div>
<div id='child2'>child2</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

you want two divs? this should work

```
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<div id="contairofthemall" style="width: 100%;">

  <div id="divone" style="height:100%; width:250px; position: absolute;"></div>
  <div id="divtwo" style="height:100%; width:100%;  "></div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: if you wanna make sure that it works just give them two different background-colors

Comment: you can add display: block; attribute to div number 2

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {}

#parent{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
   }

#child1{
  width:250px;
  background-color:green;
  }

#child2{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
<div id='child1'>child1</div>
<div id='child2'>child2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to you, Suchit ^^